# LibGDX - how to change FreeType Font color and screen coordinates

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How can I change my `FreeType` Font color? I want to set custom color. I tried do this by using `Color color = new Color()` but don't work.

And second: can I change my screen coordinates? I use two different cameras. First camera for game and second for text. When I draw text in the (0,0) position, my text is in the center of the screen but I want to have (0,0) in the lower left corner. How do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate a font you get a `BitmapFont` object.

You can set it's color like this:

```
BitmapFont someFont = freeTypeGenerator.getFont(); // or something like that
someFont.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Also, it's better to change widgets colors, not fonts, for example if you have a Label with the font created above, you can change label's color:

```
label.setColor(Color.RED);
```

For coordinates read about viewports here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

**How to create a color?**

Colors in our world contain 4 values - R, G, B and A which means red, green, blue and alpha channel.

RGB are for colors and A is for transparency.

If you want your color to be *RED*, you set *RED* to 1, *BLUE* to 0 and *GREEN* to 0

If you want your color to be *HALF RED* and *HALF BLUE* you set *RED* to 0.5f, *BLUE* to 0.5f and *GREEN* to 0f.

If you look into the `LibGDX` source, Color constructor takes 4 parameters (R,G,B and A) and these values must be in range `0-1f`. It means that if you set your color to `new Color(0,0,0,1)` - it will be a black color. If you set it to `new Color(1,1,1,1)` - you'll get a white color. As you can see, maximum value for R, G, B and A is 1. So how to create Colors from RGB values like 77,55,133?
You just divide it by `255f` and you'll get your R, G and B values.

Correct way:

```
Color color = new Color(255f/255f, 183f/255f, 77f/255f, 255f/255f);
```

Comment: I tried to use `someFont.setColor(Color.RED)` and works but only when I use standard colors. When I want to use custom `Color` my font is still white

Comment: Then show me how do you create your custom color and how do you set it! :)

Comment: First I tried generate `BitmapFont` with custom color:
`Color color = new Color(255f, 183f, 77f, 255f);
parameter.color = color;
font = generator.generateFont(parameter);`
but it did not work so I tried change `BitmapFont` color:
`Color color = new Color(255f, 183f, 77f, 255f);
font.setColor = color;` and don't work :/

Comment: Try Color color = new Color(255f/255f, 183f/255f, 77f/255f, 255f/255f); and tell me if this works :) Then, I'll explain why it does! :D

Comment: Works, thank You very much :D can you tell me something abous font sizes? I design appearance of my application in Inkscape and I'm using font size 40 in my project but when I generate and draw font in my app I had a feeling that my font is smaller than in Inkscape althought both are size 40. Why one is smaller than second?

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain how to create colors. Question about font sizes deserves another question. We can't provide answers here - in comments ;) If my answer helped you, please mark it as correct and upvote if you wish! :)